Cross Compiling Qt 6.8.0 Windows x86 -> Linux aarch64: Cannot find crt1.o
I'm trying to cross-compile Qt6 on Windows 11 for a Raspberry Pi 4. The reason for this is WSL2 does not handle the Qt Creator GUI very well and I would like to be able to develop natively on Windows. I have tried Yocto/Boot2Qt with mixed results (i.e. it fails after 6 hours due to some obscure error).
I'm following a guide that I have confirmed works well for Linux: https://wiki.qt.io/Cross-Compile_Qt_6_for_Raspberry_Pi. At the moment I am seeing issues with the "basic compiler test" from Cmake, as it does not seem to be able to find libraries presumably related to Glibc even though they are present in my sysroot.
So far I have done the following on Windows:

I have successfully compiled Qt 6.8.0 for Windows from source
I have created a known working sysroot of my Raspberry Pi device on my PC and placed it adjacent to the Qt Host build. All symlinks are relative, and it has been used successfully to cross-compile from a Linux box.
I have created a toolchain file similar to the one shown in the above link. I have modified it to remove PKG_CONFIG references, as I do not have pkg-config installed. I have also removed a few other seemingly redundant bits. As such I will post it here:

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
include_guard(GLOBAL)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

set(TARGET_SYSROOT C:/Qt/6.8.0/sysroot)
set(CMAKE_SYSROOT ${TARGET_SYSROOT})

# if you use other version of gcc and g++ than gcc/g++ 9, you must change the following variables
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER aarch64-none-linux-gnu-g++)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_RPATH ${TARGET_SYSROOT})

include(CMakeInitializeConfigs)

function(cmake_initialize_per_config_variable _PREFIX _DOCSTRING)
  if (_PREFIX MATCHES "CMAKE_(C|CXX|ASM)_FLAGS")
    set(CMAKE_${CMAKE_MATCH_1}_FLAGS_INIT "${QT_COMPILER_FLAGS}")
        
    foreach (config DEBUG RELEASE MINSIZEREL RELWITHDEBINFO)
      if (DEFINED QT_COMPILER_FLAGS_${config})
        set(CMAKE_${CMAKE_MATCH_1}_FLAGS_${config}_INIT "${QT_COMPILER_FLAGS_${config}}")
      endif()
    endforeach()
  endif()


  if (_PREFIX MATCHES "CMAKE_(SHARED|MODULE|EXE)_LINKER_FLAGS")
    foreach (config SHARED MODULE EXE)
      set(CMAKE_${config}_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT "${QT_LINKER_FLAGS}")
    endforeach()
  endif()

  _cmake_initialize_per_config_variable(${ARGV})
endfunction()


I have installed the official ARM Gnu Toolchain 13.3-rel1 for AArch64 GNU/Linux target (aarch64-none-linux-gnu). I have added the bin directory to my PATH

I have added run the following command in Command Prompt: cmake ..\Src -GNinja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DINPUT_opengl=es2 -DQT_BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -DQT_BUILD_TESTS=OFF -DQT_HOST_PATH=C:/Qt/6.8.0/qt-host -DCMAKE_STAGING_PREFIX=C:/Qt/6.8.0/qt-raspi -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/qt6 -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/Qt/6.8.0/toolchain.cmake -DQT_QMAKE_TARGET_MKSPEC=devices/linux-rasp-pi4-aarch64. This is almost the identical command-line as seen in the aforementioned link.


After running the command in step 5, Cmake reports the C++ compiler is unable to compile a simple test program. The output is as follows:
The C++ compiler

    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Arm GNU Toolchain aarch64-none-linux-gnu/13.3 rel1/bin/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-g++.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/Qt/6.8.0/pibuild/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):C:/PROGRA~1/CMake/bin/ninja.exe cmTC_016b1 && [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_016b1.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
    [2/2] Linking CXX executable cmTC_016b1
    FAILED: cmTC_016b1
    cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\PROGRA~2\ARMGNU~1\133167~1.3RE\bin\AA14A4~1.EXE --sysroot=C:/Qt/6.8.0/sysroot   CMakeFiles/cmTC_016b1.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -o cmTC_016b1  -Wl,-rpath,C:/Qt/6.8.0/sysroot && cd ."
    C:/PROGRA~2/ARMGNU~1/133167~1.3RE/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/13.3.1/../../../../aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/ld.exe: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
    C:/PROGRA~2/ARMGNU~1/133167~1.3RE/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/13.3.1/../../../../aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/ld.exe: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
    C:/PROGRA~2/ARMGNU~1/133167~1.3RE/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/13.3.1/../../../../aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lm: No such file or directory
    collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

My Question (other than "what am I doing wrong?"): Why is it unable to find these libraries? I have confirmed their presence in my sysroot under /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu. As seen above, Cmake is correctly passing the --sysroot flag. Do I need to build my own cross-compiler that has the proper version of Glibc?

Set Qt aside. Write a hello world C++ program. Don't write makefiles, cmakefiles or what have you. Can you compile and link this program from the command line using just the g++ command?

This is where things get funny. I tried several things.
First program:
int main() {
  return 0;
}

With aarch64-none-linux-gnu-g++ test.cpp -o test works just fine.
With aarch64-none-linux-gnu-g++ test.cpp --sysroot sysroot -o test gives the above errors.
Second Program:
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
  cout << endl;
  return 0;
}

With no sysroot works fine. With sysroot gives me an error sysroot/usr/include/features-time64.h:20:10: fatal error: bits/wordsize.h: No such file or directory

Well perhaps your build is not designed to use sysroot? A side note, -rpath like this makes little sense, cause the finished program runs on Linux and Linux ain't got no C:/.

This is what I'm suspecting. I find it odd, though, that the cross compiler I downloaded (see above) claims to be for "aarch64 linux" and not "aarch64 bare metal." Would that make a difference, re. sysroot? Or should I just give up and build my own cross compiler?

Why? Do you plan to run your Raspberry Pi without an OS?

No. I'm just trying to understand why the compiler won't compile when given a sysroot that contains, presumably, everything it needs to know. I thought that by "not priming the compiler" i.e. using a bare metal one and providing the standard libraries via sysroot, it might just work (it didn't; I already tried). I simply want to understand what I'm doing wrong and what I need to do so g++ will work with a sysroot, which is necessary for cross-compiling Qt.

Hmm I probably misunderstood tour question. Try adding --verbose to your g++ command without --sysroot=. Note where it locates crt1.o. Is the position of your crt1.o relative to your sysroot the same?

No, I don't think so. I think you've identified the problem. It's looking at C:/Program Files (x86)/Arm GNU Toolchain aarch64-none-linux-gnu/13.3 rel1/bin/../aarch64-none-linux-gnu/libc/usr/lib/../lib64/crt1.o whereas crt1.o in my sysroot is in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu. Looks like I'll need my own cross-compiler. Thanks for your input.
